How to format Jenkins shared library docs
I have successfull build a Jenkins Shared library.
In the vars folder are

lbrCall.groovy
lbrCall.txt

I am missing something on formatting the documenatation of the lbrCall.txt.
The documentation in the pipeline-syntax/globals can be found.
Sadly i can't make it work with markdown and other formats. The formatted output is always raw.
This is the documentation I have found.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#directory-structure
What am I missing?
Has somebody an example of a non text documentation.

Jenkins defaults to the "Plain test" markup formatter, but it's configurable under Manage Jenkins -> Security -> Markup Formatter. Change it "Safe HTML" to render HTML help.

Sadly i can't try this. So i can't mark this as accepted because i can't validate even though i belive this to be the correct answer. Sorry.
